# jQuery ajax call to asmx issues with functions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a form that I am submitting using an ajax call to an asmx web service. The data successfully inserts into the database, however; neither the success or error function is being triggered. The first alert works. Any ideas?

My jQuery:

```
        $("#AddSupplierBtn").click(function()
        {

            alert("This is the first alert");
            if ($("#AddSupplier").valid())
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/StockPileDelivery.asmx/TestMethod",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        SupplierName: $('#SupplierName').val(),
                        SupplierType: $('#SupplierType').val(),
                        SupplierPremium: $('#SupplierPremium').val(),
                        SupplierLocation: $('#SupplierLocation').val()
                    }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Working - " + msg.d);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr,status,error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        alert(err.Message);
                    },
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: does your webpage is reloading after ajax call? also check browser console for any JS error

Comment: what do you mean by "The first alert works." ??? the one within success??

Comment: Yes the page is reloading and I uploaded the code to show the alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the below button type from submit to button and it worked:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="AddSupplierBtn" name="AddSupplierBtn">Submit</button>
```